# Commerce - PayPal WPS - Two orders created

Tags: commerce, payment-gateways

I have a weird problem when using PayPal WPS with Drupal Commerce. Everything seems to work fine from a client perspective, except that the order gets status pending. The problem is that two orders are created. One pending order for the user with the PayPal transaction and for the right amount, and one completed order for a guest user for $0.

Does anyone know what might cause this problem?

Comment: It must be the rules issue. You should look into the list of rules for that..

Comment: Just to rule something out for you, there's nothing in a normal installation of PayPal WPS that would create a duplicate order. Are you sure it's limited to that payment method?

Comment: It was a rules issue. Found a rule that were doing multiple actions and one of them was to create a new order.